# Different Set-ItemProperty behavior, console vs ISE

Tags: powershell

I am doing some data gathering that requires opening the registry to the uninstall key on multiple VMs, so I am looking to automate that process. This works a treat when running it from the ISE.

```
function Open-Registry {
    param($regKey)

    $path = $path -Replace '^HKCU:', 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER' -Replace '^HKLM:', 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' -Replace '^HKCR:', 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT' -Replace '^HKCC:', 'HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG' -Replace '^HKU:', 'HKEY_USERS' 
    if (Test-Path "Registry::$path") {
        Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit\' -Name:LastKey -Value:$path -Force
        $regeditInstance = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start("regedit","-m")
    }
}
Open-Registry 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
```

However, ultimately I want to pass the path argument to the script, and potentially use a shortcut with the argument (this the reason to support shorthand hive names). At minimum, I would rather run the script in the console than from the ISE. And when I run this in the console it DOES open RegEdit, but not at the desired location, but rather root. Given that the registry property (LastKey) being modified to get the desired effect is in the Current User hive, I would not expect any issues here. Indeed, in other, much more complicated code, I modify Current User keys quite often. So, what is happening in this very simple situation to change, I assume, the behavior of `Set-ItemProperty` in the console vs ISE?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to automate the task completely (rather than automate opening `regedit` for manual intervention)?

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Ultimately yes, but the data I need to gather is data from Autodesk programs, and ADSK changes things EVERY SINGLE YEAR, for no reason other than incompetence and spite I think. So actually automating is really hard, since there isn't consistency in the data year over year, nor even program to program. So I can save myself a little time at least opening Regedit where I need it. I COULD also have LastKey right before I start doing installs, so all the snapshots already work right, but I forgot to do that this year, and there is one program that requires looking in HKCR too. :(

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Plus, now I am just curious about the difference in behavior too.

Comment: As an aside, on my machine (Windows 11) when I manually navigate to "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" in regedit and close the app it sets the LastKey to ```Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall``` (prefixed with ```Computer\```).

Comment: @mclayton Ah, that's interesting! I haven't started testing much on Win 11 yet, but I fully expect Microsoft to break all sorts of things. :)

Comment: This line, `$path = $path -Replace ...` should be, `$path = $regKey -Replace ...` ?

Comment: @todd And the ISE works because the $path variable is still populated from previous playing around. Ugh! I feel like a dolt. :)

Comment: Don't feel bad.. there are 5 responses, and nobody's noticed this until now =)